# Por que a Activity é instanciada duas vezes?

Tags: java, android, facebook

Estou implementando o sdk do facebook para fazer login no meu aplicativo. Tenho duas Activities que chamo de Login e Home.
Quando clico no botão de login, o login é realizado perfeitamente e a Activity Home é instanciada assim que o método onSessionStateChange é chamado:

```
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,
        Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), HomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        getActivity().finish();
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
    }

}
```

O problema é que o código instância duas vezes a activity Home.

Comment: Tente fazer um override do `onBackPressed` na activity Home. Verifique se está logado e apenas finalize a activity Home sem chamar método super (deve haver uma solução melhor).

Comment: Eu fiz isso mesmo, mas como vc disse, não acho que seja a melhor solução.

Comment: Você tem que finalizar a acitivity da nova activity que você tá chamando, não?

Comment: Sim. Quando se pressiona o botão voltar do dispositivo acontece exatamente isso.

Comment: Digo, passa no `Bundle` da `intent` a referência pra activity login e, ao iniciar a outra activity, finaliza a activity de login.

Comment: Editei a pergunta

Comment: Essa edição muda muita coisa. Se você tem duas instâncias da HomeActivity você vai ter que mostrar mais código, porque o problema com certeza não está ai.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe uma grande chance de o callback `onSessionStateChange` está sendo chamado mais de uma vez com o mesmo estado.

Existem cenários em que isso pode acontecer como por exemplo o ponto em que você está fazendo sua chamada inicial.

Se for no `onResume` tente mudar para que fique no `onCreate`.